# Previous song won't stop AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flash-cc

This code won't stop the previous song if I'm changing songs in the combobox. The new song starts playing, but as mentioned, the old doesn't stop. Please help me with this schoolproject.

```
import flash.net.URLLoader;
import flash.net.URLRequest;
import flash.events.Event;
import fl.data.DataProvider;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
var url:URLRequest = new URLRequest("xml/xmlSanger.xml");
var xml:XML;
var dp:DataProvider = new DataProvider(); 

dropdown2.addEventListener(Event.CHANGE, visSang); 

loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, lastetXML); 
loader.load(url);

function lastetXML(evt:Event) {
    xml = new XML(loader.data);
    fyllComboBoks(); 
}

function fyllComboBoks(){
    var antallSanger = xml.sang.length();
    for(var teller:int = 0; teller < antallSanger; teller++)
    {
        dp.addItem({label:xml.sang[teller].navn[0]});
    }

dropdown2.dataProvider = dp; 
dropdown2.selectedIndex = 0;

}

function visSang (evt:Event){
    soundClip.stop();
    var soundClip:Sound = new Sound();
    var id:uint = dropdown2.selectedIndex;
    trace (id);
    songname.text = xml.sang[id].navn[0];
    artistname.text = xml.sang[id].artistname[0];
    var filbane = xml.sang[id].fil[0];
    soundClip.load(new URLRequest(filbane));    
    soundClip.play();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare soundClip outside of visSang, so you can access it when you call the function again.

```
import flash.net.URLLoader;
import flash.net.URLRequest;
import flash.events.Event;
import fl.data.DataProvider;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
var url:URLRequest = new URLRequest("xml/xmlSanger.xml");
var xml:XML;
var dp:DataProvider = new DataProvider(); 
var soundClip:Sound;

dropdown2.addEventListener(Event.CHANGE, visSang); 

loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, lastetXML); 
loader.load(url);

function lastetXML(evt:Event) {
    xml = new XML(loader.data);
    fyllComboBoks(); 
}

function fyllComboBoks(){
    var antallSanger = xml.sang.length();
    for(var teller:int = 0; teller < antallSanger; teller++)
    {
        dp.addItem({label:xml.sang[teller].navn[0]});
    }

dropdown2.dataProvider = dp; 
dropdown2.selectedIndex = 0;

}

function visSang (evt:Event){
    soundClip.stop();
    soundClip = new Sound();
    var id:uint = dropdown2.selectedIndex;
    trace (id);
    songname.text = xml.sang[id].navn[0];
    artistname.text = xml.sang[id].artistname[0];
    var filbane = xml.sang[id].fil[0];
    soundClip.load(new URLRequest(filbane));    
    soundClip.play();
}
```